# Replace multiple statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Given the following code:

```js
if (CONDITION1) {
  if (CONDITION2) {
    if (CONDITION3) {
      if (CONDITION4) {
        if (CONDITION5) {

        } else {
          return ('STOP IN CONDITION5')
        }
      } else {
        return ('STOP IN CONDITION4')
      }
    } else {
      return ('STOP IN CONDITION3')
    }
  } else {
    return ('STOP IN CONDITION2')
  }
} else {
  return ('STOP IN CONDITION1')
}
```

I need to replace these multiple `if` statements for some other code using good practices and for cleaner reading for other people in future.

Comment: The elses are likely unnecessary. Try `if(!condition) { return ... }`?

Comment: If the `if` conditional is not doing anything, you could even drop the curly braces (and the grouping operator as well): `if(!conditionX) return "stop in conditionX";`.

Comment: Please don't drop the braces as suggested above. It looks horrible, it's easier to make mistakes and most linters require them by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could flatten this by testing for **not** condition:

```
function doStuff() {
  if (!CONDITION1) {
    return ('STOP IN CONDITION1')
  }

  if (!CONDITION2) {
    return ('STOP IN CONDITION2')
  }

  if (!CONDITION3) {
    return ('STOP IN CONDITION3')
  }

  if (!CONDITION4) {
    return ('STOP IN CONDITION4')
  }

  if (!CONDITION5) {
    return ('STOP IN CONDITION5')
  }
}
```

Note: in between the `if`s you could add code for condition `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered and I **wouldn't** recommend this version (linters probably complain, flat `if` statements are fine) but I'm throwing it in there to show another possibility.

You can potentially use a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement and add your conditions to each case:

```js
const CONDITION1 = 1 > 2
const CONDITION2 = 2 < 1

const run = () => {
  switch(true) { // always evaluate this switch
    case !CONDITION1: 
      return 'STOP IN CONDITION1'
    case !CONDITION2:
      return 'STOP IN CONDITION1'
    // etc...
  }
}

console.log(run())
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using Array.prototype.findIndex()

- Store your conditions into Array
- Use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). Just return the argument itself `(x) => x`, it fill be treated as `boolean` and if `true` the method will return the **index**. Store the returned integer into a variable `errIndex`.
- If `errIndex` is greater than `-1` that means you have an *"error"* in the `conditions` array at that index

```js
const conditions = [false, false, true, false, false];

const errIndex = conditions.findIndex(x => x);

if (errIndex > -1) {
  console.log(`STOP IN CONDITION ${errIndex + 1}`);
} else {
  console.log("All passed");
}
```

The nice thing about using .findIndex() is in that it can short-circuit the search and immediately return the index.

---

Not sure why, but given you want to `return` a String, and since `return` statements are used within a function, and since it's always preferable for a function to return the same *type*,
you could create a function that accepts an array of conditions and a success string as the second argument:

```js
const status = (conditions, successMsg) => {
  const idx = conditions.findIndex(x=>x);
  return idx < 0 ? successMsg : `STOP IN CONDITION ${idx+1}`;
};

console.log(status([false, false, true, false, false], "OK"));  // STOP IN CONDITION 3
console.log(status([false, false, false, false, false], "OK")); // OK
```

or you can create something similar based on the above idea, like a `pass` function in which you do not hardcode error strings, but instead it provides you with a callback function with argument being an Object with index property or `null`

```js
const pass = (conditions, fn) => {
  const index = conditions.findIndex(x => x);
  fn(index < 0 ? null : {index});
};


pass([false, false, true, false, false], (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`STOP IN CONDITION ${err.index + 1}`)
    return; // Exit function here
  }
  // All OK...
  console.log("All OK! Do some work here");
});
```